# If statement in selenium python test

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to add `If statement` in selenium python test to check if certain element is located then we execute block of code, else continue execution of test.

In Protractor/Typescript I had a function like this:

```js
elements.element1.isPresent().then(async(result)=> {
            if (result){
                elements.element1.click();
                elements.element2.click();
            }else{
```

Comment: `if result:....` what have you tried in python? please share your code

Comment: I found the solution, see answer and comment below,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the simple snippet.

```
if len(elements)>0:
    # access the first element and perform operation here
    ele1 = elements[0]
```

Comment: So I used `find_elements` which returns empty list if no elements found and then I took yours `if len()>0` to proceed with extra steps. Thank you for fast response!